# Tax implication for a Temporary Resident in Australia while in another country?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, australia, foreign-income, visa

I am a student in Australia (making me a Temporary Resident for Tax Purposes), and an Indian citizen. I work as a sole trader / self-employed individual (web development freelancing), and according to ATO's website:

> Most of your foreign income is not taxed in Australia except income earned from employment or services performed overseas while you are a temporary resident.

Does this mean the income I earn as a freelancer while in India during my temporary residency (e.g. during summer vacation) is also taxable in Australia?